# MailboxProcessor Scan memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, f#, mailboxprocessor

Consider the following agent which uses `Scan` to process every message, with a message posted every millisecond.

```ml
open System.Threading

let mp = MailboxProcessor<string>.Start (fun inbox ->
    let rec await () = inbox.Scan (fun msg ->
        printfn "Received : %s" msg
        printfn "Queue length: %i" inbox.CurrentQueueLength
        Some <| await ())
    await ())
while true do
    mp.Post "word"
    Thread.Sleep 1
```

If I monitor the memory usage of the process (macOS, via Activity Monitor), it grows and grows. Yet you can see from the printout that the queue length remains at 0.

Is this a memory leak bug in `Scan` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried forcing a garbage collection via `System.GC.Collect()`? Memory usage naturally increases between garbage collections.

Comment: @BrianBerns Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and it makes no material difference.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be tail recursive. The function calls itself, but then pipes the result into Some before returning. Why use Scan instead of Receive?

Comment: @BentTranberg The scanner function must return an `Async<unit> option`. I'm using `Scan` to demonstrate the issue with `Scan`.

Comment: Your message loop function isn’t properly formed. Re write as a while loop doing the scan inside the loop to se why.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my guess. The await function calls itself, but not with tail recursion, since you're piping the result of the call into Some. That's why memory consumption grows. So yes, try with a loop instead.

Comment: Not to be harsh, but I would describe your code as nonsensical. I'm actually surprised it even compiles, though someone who understands the compiler better might be able to explain that. Then again, maybe it's a compiler bug.

Comment: You're right. Here's how it's used, with no leak: https://www.codemag.com/article/1707051/Writing-Concurrent-Programs-Using-F

Comment: @BentTranberg Thanks. That resolves it. I hadn't suspected that that could be the problem because I found the pattern in the question in _Expert F# 4.0_ by Syme et al..

Comment: I'm thinking that as an example in a book there was perhaps not an intention of having a tail recursive loop. I do have the book, but don't have the time to look into it, literally. Even though it would be interesting.